# Exporting signal data from figure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is it somehow possible to get signal data from figure, to save the vector or matrix of the data to the Workspace?

We happend to make a lots of measurements on a real system in school, but ve saved only figures of the measutrement and now we need to use some of the signals from the figure and use them in another figure for comparison.

Comment: If you saved them as a .fig, then this example might do it: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100687

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the figure in Matlab and go to View->Properties, to pull the data out of the plot's properties e.g. for a line graph plot:

[image]

You can get at the XData and YData properties and copy/paste the values of out it e.g.

[image]

Alternatively, as I had to do once when this method failed, you can save the figure as EPS/postscript and try to pull the data out of the postscript file in a text editor (!)